# How to hide some references in biblatex?

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex

I've almost figured out how to cite a multi-volume book (as per [my other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16514/how-to-reference-a-multi-volume-book-with-bibtex)).
I've separated it into 3 entities - and then used Set to put it into bibliography.

```
@Book{Boncompagni_2_vol,
  author="Boncompagni, Baldassarre",
  title="Scritti di Leonardo Pisano matematico del secolo decimoterzo.",
  address="Roma", 
  publisher="Tipografia delle scienze matematiche e fisiche",
  date={1857/1862},
  volumes = {2},
  note="(in Lat.)"
}
@Book{Boncompagni_vol_1,
  volume = {I},
  title="Leonardi Pisani, Liber Abbaci = Il Liber Abbaci di Leonardo Pisano.",
  date={1857},
  pagetotal={459},
}
@Book{Boncompagni_vol_2,
  volume={II},
  title= "Leonardi Pisani Practica geometriae ed opuscoli = La Practica Geometriae di Leonardo Pisano; Opuscoli di Leonardo Pisano.",
  date={1862},
  pagetotal={283},
}

@Set{Boncompagni_collection,
  entryset={Boncompagni_2_vol, Boncompagni_vol_1, Boncompagni_vol_2},
}
```

However, the problem is that now I have 4 references showing up - 3 originals and 1 set.
I've used the `\nocite{*}` to always show all references.

Is there a way to hide only 3 of those references while printing everything else?

EDIT: Well it seems that by using @Set I automatically get all the individual entries hidden. So this question itself is wrong. But it still applies if the @Set is not present.

Comment: I suppose that the conventions are probably different in your field, but in the social sciences where I work, I think most people(/editors/journals) would prefer that volumes published separately and in separate years be referenced to separate entries in the bibliography (somewhat similarly to how  articles by different authors compiled into a book are cited -- one entry per article that you reference, no entry for the book as a whole).  "Make sure this is what you want" is my message, I guess.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Aussuming that you are using the `biblatex` package there are several ways of hiding entries in the bibliography:

- To exclude a certain entry just use `options = {skipbib=true}`

  ```
  @Book{Boncompagni_2_vol,
  author="Boncompagni, Baldassarre",
  title="Scritti di Leonardo Pisano matematico del secolo decimoterzo.",
  address="Roma", 
  publisher="Tipografia delle scienze matematiche e fisiche",
  date={1857/1862},
  volumes = {2},
  note="(in Lat.)",
  options = {skipbib=true}
  }
  ```
- You can also hide certain types of entries using specifying `nottype` or `type` in `\printbibliography`

  ```
  \printbibliography[nottype=online,title={Printed Sources}] % shows all entries excluding @online
  \printbibliography[type=online,title={Online Sources}] % shows only @online entries
  ```

There are many other ways `biblatex` can display bibliography entries. To see more examples have a look at http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/

Comment: Thanks. How do I indicate that the type is "online"?

Comment: By using the actual @online type. Of course, you shouldn't change @book to @online to achieve that. You could do something similar with book or set types.

Comment: @drozzy This was just an example for the usage of `type`. In your example you should write `\printbibliography[type=book]` if you only want to display entries of the `@book` type. The `@online` type I mentioned above is just another type `biblatex` supports. It is used for online ressources. There is a list of all entry types in the `biblatex` [manual](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/archive/Archive%20directory/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) from page 6 on.

Comment: You know what's weird? When I use @Set - the Set itself shows up - but others do not. I didn't even need to use any of your suggestions... I just never noticed that @Set hides the individual entries. Does that seem right?

Comment: Yes, if an entry is a set member and the set is cited, then it's not listed as a stand-alone entry. This applies only within a refsection and the behaviour is reset between refsections. See the biblatex manual 3.10.5.

Answer (score 3):

You can include the field `options = {skipbib=true},` for the entries you don't want printed.